# iOS - Issue with passing Dictionary as parameter from AFNetworking GET

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to pass a dictionary received from a `GET` request using `AFNetworking` to a `class method parameter`. But I am getting this error.

```
+[SASwipeButtonSettings performActionForLeftSwipeWithVideo:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3a42a8
2015-06-29 15:03:38.526 StreamacyBeta[3712:1057453] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

This is how I am retrieving the data and passing it.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:youtubeApi parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.videos = responseObject[@"items"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];



-(BOOL)swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell *)cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL)fromExpansion
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell];
    NSDictionary *selectedVideo = self.videos[indexPath.row];

    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionLeftToRight) {
        [SASwipeButtonSettings performActionForLeftSwipeWithVideo:selectedVideo];
    }  
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas why I am having this issue? The parameter on my method just accepts an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: performActionForLeftSwipeWithVideo is this method exists with same parameter which you have passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your class `SASwipeButtonSettings` does not implement static method `performActionForLeftSwipeWithVideo` that takes an `NSDictionary*`. It does not appear to be an AFNetworking issue.

Comment: Agreed, check your signature for `performActionForLeftSwipeWithVideo` and ensure that is declared as with `+` (class/static method) vs `-` (instance method).

Comment: @Andy unfortunately it happens all the time :) This is why peer code  reviews helps.

Comment: @Andy do not forget to accept as an answer, since it helped :)

Comment: just did was waiting till it would allow me. thanks again